# MapStruct Incorrect Conversion

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm trying to map a SectionTargetingRule from one object to another object with similar name and structure. The issue I'm facing is that mapstruct is complaining about trying to map between 2 objects that it shouldn't be. Below is the make up of my datastructures

**Targets**:

```
public class SectionTargetingGroup {
    public String name;
    public List<TargetingTuple> items;
}

public class SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude {
    static final SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude DEFAULT = new SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude();
    public List<SectionTargetingGroup> include = Lists.newArrayList();
    public List<SectionTargetingGroup> exclude = Lists.newArrayList();
}

public class SectionTargetingRule extends TargetingRule {

    static final SectionTargetingRule DEFAULT = new SectionTargetingRule();

    public int version;
    public SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude items = SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude.DEFAULT;
}
```

**Sources**:

```
public class SectionTargetingGroup {
    private String name;
    private List<TargetingTuple> items;
}

public class SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude {
    private List<SectionTargetingGroup> include;
    private List<SectionTargetingGroup> exclude;
}

public class SectionTargetingRule {
    private Integer version;
    private SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude items;
}
```

**The Error**:
Mapstruct throws this error:

```
...ProfileMapper.java:147: error: Can't map property "SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude items" to "List<TargetingTuple> items". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "List<TargetingTuple> map(SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude value)".
    SectionTargetingRule toExchangeSectionRule(
```

MapStruct is complaining that it's trying to convert a SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude -> List which clearly isn't right given the data structures above.

**Mapping interface methods:**

Here are my mapping interface methods

```
@Mapper(
        componentModel = "spring",
        collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
        nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
public interface ProfileMapper {
@Named("sectionTargetingRule")
@Mapping(source="version", target = "version")
@Mapping(source="items", target = "items")
//  @Mapping(target = "items", ignore = true)
SectionTargetingRule toExchangeSectionRule(
        com.jmoncayo.types.SectionTargetingRule sectionTargetingRule);

@Mapping(source = "include", target = "include")
@Mapping(source = "exclude", target = "exclude")
SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude
toExchangeSectionTargetIncludeExclude(
        com.jmoncayo.types.SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude sectionTargetingRule);

List<SectionTargetingGroup> toExchangeSectionTargetingGroups(List<com.jmoncayo.types.SectionTargetingGroup> sectionTargetingGroups);

@Mapping(source = "name", target="name")
@Mapping(source = "items", target="items")
SectionTargetingGroup toExchangeSectionTarget(
        com.jmoncayo.types.SectionTargetingGroup sectionTargetingGroup);
}
```

Why is MapStruct trying to convert a SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude to a List? If I uncomment `//Mapping(target = "items", ignore = true)` then it works fine but for some reason that field is causing issues

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-object-references)

> When generating the implementation of a mapping method, MapStruct will
> apply the following routine for each attribute pair in the source and
> target object:
>
> 1. If source and target attribute have the same type, the value will be
>    simply copied direct from source to target. If the attribute is a
>    collection (e.g. a List) a copy of the collection will be set into the
>    target attribute.
> 2. If source and target attribute type differ, check whether there is
>    another mapping method which has the type of the source attribute as
>    parameter type and the type of the target attribute as return type. If
>    such a method exists it will be invoked in the generated mapping
>    implementation.
> 3. If no such method exists MapStruct will look whether a built-in
>    conversion for the source and target type of the attribute exists. If
>    this is the case, the generated mapping code will apply this
>    conversion.
> 4. If no such method exists MapStruct will apply complex conversions:
>
>    a. mapping method, the result mapped by mapping method, like this: target
>    = method1( method2( source ) )
>
>    b. built-in conversion, the result mapped by mapping method, like this:
>    target = method( conversion( source ) )
>
>    c. mapping method, the result mapped by build-in conversion, like this:
>    target = conversion( method( source ) )
> 5. If no such method was found MapStruct will try to generate an
>    automatic sub-mapping method that will do the mapping between the
>    source and target attributes.
> 6. **If MapStruct could not create a name based mapping method an error
>    will be raised at build time, indicating the non-mappable attribute
>    and its path.**

I suppose you fallen in case #6 when by-name mapping is not possibile due to conversion rules; add `@mapping(ignore=true)` fix the error because rule #6 is skipped.

Comment: but then wouldn't this have resolved the issue?

`@Mapping(source = "include", target = "include")
@Mapping(source = "exclude", target = "exclude")
SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude
toExchangeSectionTargetIncludeExclude(
        com.jmoncayo.types.SectionTargetingGroupIncludeExclude sectionTargetingRule);
`